# How to see a column for the release date of a Version in JIRA?

Tags: jira

When filtering, is there a way to have a column that returns the "Release Date" of a Version?
Seems simple but it doubt it's built-in.
Is there a way with ScriptRunner?
I'm using JIRA V 6.4.1

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can include only issue custom fields into the filter. You can create your own custom field that would return release date of version.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Robert
You can include only issue custom fields into the filter. You can create your own custom field that would return release date of version.